# Find OS X terminal key combination/escape sequence for Ctrl-'

Tags: bash, emacs, sed

One of my Emacs keybindings is `C-'`, which works well in GUI. In terminal however, it is not being recognised. I understand that I need to figure out the actual characters sent to the terminal by `C-'` and map it in the emacs config.

Following the advice of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-terminal-key-codes-to-remap-shortcuts-in-bash, `sed -n l` is returning back to me a an empty line, even without the ending `$`. Does Terminal not recognise the `C-'` sequence at all?

Comment: Have you tried `C-h k C-'` to see what emacs thinks the key is when run in a terminal?

Comment: Yeah I did. Nothing, it doesn't recognise the input at all. Using `od -c` also shows nothing. I think my terminal simply doesn't recognise it at all and it needs to be added somehow.

Comment: With apple terminal and bash I have no problem seeing this key combination in emacs running in the terminal, but neither `sed -n l` nor `od -c` return anything.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your terminal emulator. Emacs-the-GUI essentially is a terminal plus Emacs, so it is reading keystrokes directly from the keyboard (well, via the OS, but you can ignore that detail). As such, it can interpret any keystroke it receives. Your terminal emulator, however, is by default treating Control-' as a plain ', so you'll have to configure it to pass a different character (or character sequence) through to whatever process is running in the current terminal window.

Comment: How can I do that? To basically allow terminal to recognise `Ctrl-'`?

Comment: That's off-topic for Stack Overflow.